# 301 redirects and SEO

Tags: google, seo, search-engine

I have a site which uses the following structure,

domain.com/12/43/45/some-post/

When people link to my site some cms's remove the trailing slash and turn it into,

domain.com/12/43/45/some-post

both URL's refer to the same content, my question is is this considered duplicate content should i do a 301 redirect to the top url?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com, but is too old to be migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google generally looks at these pages as different pages, although it's my understanding that Google is working on better assuring whether they are or are not the same content.

For now, a re-direct isn't a bad idea. Want to test for yourself? Browse around like one guy did you and you'll see [different page ranks](https://serverfault.com/questions/96340/301-redirects-and-seo) on for different trailing slash/no-trailing slash combos.